# How to use select() inside between() inside filter() to subset data dplyr r

Tags: r, select, dplyr, filter, between

What I have:
I have a large dataset with columns for a few measured variables, SiteID and Seconds.

What I would like to do:
For each of my study sites (`SiteID`), I would like to filter out rows for a specific time period (`Seconds`). I have the following code, which works only if the values in `Seconds` are unique to each study site, for example:

```
# create example data
data <- data.frame(SiteID = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), each = 10),
                   Seconds = rep(c(1:50)))

# filter the data
data.subset <- data %>%
  filter(between(Seconds, 2, 8) | # for SiteID = "A"
  filter(between(Seconds, 14, 16) | # for SiteID = "B"
  filter(between(Seconds, 23, 30) | # for SiteID = "C"
  filter(between(Seconds, 36, 39) | # for SiteID = "D"
  filter(between(Seconds, 44, 49)) # for SiteID = "E"
```

The code above would give me what I want, which is:

```
SiteID    Seconds 
A         2
A         3
A         4
A         5
A         6
A         7
A         8
B         14
B         15
B         16
C         23
C         24
C         25
C         26
C         27
C         28
C         29
C         30
D         36
D         37
D         38
D         39
E         44
E         45
E         46
E         47
E         48
E         49
```

What problem I'm facing: The problem I have is that in my dataset, the range of `Seconds` for each `SiteID` are not unique as in the example above, but looks more like the following:

```
# create example data
data <- data.frame(SiteID = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), each = 10),
                   Seconds = rep(c(1:10)))
```

But I would like to subset the data as such: For site A, keep only 2-8 seconds. For site B, keep only 3-6 seconds. For site C, keep only 8-10 seconds. For site D, keep only 1-6 seconds. For site E, keep only 2-9 seconds.

I need help modifying the dplyr code above for me to do this. If I used the same code as above, the data set remains exactly the same and is not filtered the way I want it to because the numbers for each `SiteID` are in a similar range. I have tried using `select()` as the first term inside `between()` to filter out only the rows with a specific `SiteID`, but it is returning an error:

```
# modified code 
data.subset <- data %>%
  filter(between(select(data, Seconds & SiteID == "A"), 2, 8) | 
  filter(between(select(data, Seconds & SiteID == "B"), 3, 6) | 
  filter(between(select(data, Seconds & SiteID == "C"), 8, 10) |
  filter(between(select(data, Seconds & SiteID == "D"), 1, 6) | 
  filter(between(select(data, Seconds & SiteID == "E"), 2, 9))
```

```
#  error message:
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `between(...)`.
x Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `logical`.
i It must be numeric or character.
```

Basically if I were to use base R, I would need to do something like the following as the first term inside the between() function in place of just `Seconds`:

```
data$Seconds[data$SiteID == "A"]
```

I hope it is clear what I'm trying to do with dplyr. My desired outcome would look like this:

```
SiteID    Seconds  
A         2
A         3
A         4
A         5
A         6
A         7
A         8
B         3
B         4
B         5
B         6
C         8
C         9
C         10
D         1
D         2
D         3
D         4
D         5
D         6
E         2
E         3
E         4
E         5
E         6
E         7
E         8
E         9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine multiple conditions using `&` -

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  filter(SiteID == "A" & between(Seconds, 2, 8) | 
         SiteID == "B" & between(Seconds, 3, 6) | 
         SiteID == "C" & between(Seconds, 8, 10)|
         SiteID == "D" & between(Seconds, 1, 6) | 
         SiteID == "E" & between(Seconds, 2, 9))
```

Comment: Thank you! And suppose I have 10000 different SiteID, how can I replace SiteID == "A" with something like unique(data$SiteID)[1],  SiteID == "B" with unique(data$SiteID)[2], etc. but in dplyr? I tried SiteID[1] for SiteID == "A" but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can use `SiteID == unique(SiteID)[1]` i.e `SiteID == unique(SiteID)[1] & between(Seconds, 2, 8)` would be the 1st condition and so on for other ones.